# Does Chat-GPT learn from interactions?

Tags: training, chatgpt

Does Chat-GPT accumulate knowledge through interactions with users in real time? I know it's trained on a massive dataset but does it do online learning?

Comment: Questions about specific products are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core model for ChatGPT, a Large Language Model (LLM), is *not* updated in real time during chats.

The chat history *can* be saved, and if so used by OpenAI to train models for future releases.

You can see this option in Settings:

[image: ChatGPT data control settings showing training option]

However, there have been leaked/previewed plans for changes to the higher level software (i.e. the input/output control that *uses* the model), and as part of that OpenAI have added a mechanism whereby the bot will somehow store key data from conversations, and use this data to customise responses. As an educated guess, this is probably a text summary (generated by an LLM reading the conversations) stored as reference data or as a second "system prompt". This new feature in progress [has been labelled "Project Sunshine" by commenters](https://community.openai.com/t/project-sunshine-live-i-just-saw-a-popup-explaining-a-new-memory-feature-i-am-curious-and-would-love-to-learn-more-about-how-chatgpt-stores-data-between-sessions-more/580226). OpenAI have not formally confirmed this or released details of how that works AFAICS, but it seems like the ability to enable this, and to clear this personalised memory, will also appear in Settings.

Comment: Honestly it should retrain itself on accumulated data(perhaps it will in the future). Eventually you will get novel conversations where each bot is talking to another bot.

Comment: @FourierFlux but retraining is expensive and cause catastrophic forgetting if not done properly